# Sorting CSS elements in Netbeans

Tags: css, netbeans

Is there a way to sort the elements in a CSS file while formatting, in Netbeans ?

Comment: See Window -> Web -> Css Styles. A panel with a list of all rules should appear. It is sorted. Never seen some sorting function for css. And I'm not sure if there is any reason to do that. Remember that applied styles may depend on order of rules.